# Need a C++ library to convert excel files from 1995 to new ones

Tags: c++, excel

I was wondering if anyone knows of a C++ utility that can convert a 1995 .xls file (Microsoft Excel v7.0) into an excel file form 1997 or later.

It doesn't need to be free.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but the most reliable tool I've used for reading and writing Excel files is Excel itself.  It should not be difficult using the Office Tools to create a program that uses Excel's automation interfaces to read a file in the older format, and save it out again in the newer format.

Comment: Would this require anyone using the program to have Excel installed? I am just using excel files as an intermediary to convert Formula 1 spreadsheet files into Farpoint Spread spreadsheet files so the users wouldn't necessarily have Excel. Anyway I'll look into it.

thanks